# Dart Testing: can I configure platforms to skip certain tags?

Tags: dart

With `dart_test.yaml` it is easy to configure tests with a particular tag to be skipped, with perhaps an override. For example, configure the chromeUnstableOnly tag to cause skipping on all platforms, with a "-P force" preset to make them run:

```
tags:
  chromeUnstableOnly:
    skip: "Not implemented on stable yet"
    presets: {force: {skip: false}}
```

In the tests themselves I can configure a skip for a particular platform:

```
test('Foo Test', () {
  // ...
}, onPlatform: {
  'chrome_stable': new Skip('Not yet supported on stable.')
});
```

Is it possible to configure platform-specific skipping based on tags in `dart_test.yaml` so that unit tests with a 'chromeUnstableOnly' tag is skipped on other platforms? I want to define my tests as follows:

```
test('Foo Test', () {
  // ...
}, tags: ['chromeUnstableOnly']);
```

I can define presets, and have presets select platforms:

```
# This works, but can I set a default preset for "pub run"?
presets:
  stable:
    exclude_tags: chromeUnstable
    platforms:
      - chrome_stable
```

I can't find a way to specify a default preset though. It also doesn't seem to work to use exclude_tags or add_presets under platforms:

```
define_platforms:
  chrome_stable_with_exclude_tags
    name: Chrome Stable
    extends: chrome
    exclude_tags: [chromeUnstableOnly]  # does not seem to work
  chrome_stable_with_preset
    name: Chrome Stable
    extends: chrome
    add_presets: [stable]  # does not seem to work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to skip tests with certain tags on certain platforms by adding on_platform fields to tags:

```
tags:
  chromeUnstableOnly:
    on_platform:
      chrome_stable:
        skip: "Not implemented on stable yet. Use -P force to force tests."
        presets: {force: {skip: false}}
```

Comment: Note that skipping with "on_platform: chrome" seems to skip all platforms defined via "extends: chrome". I'm not yet sure how to neatly skip "chrome" while still running something that "extends: chrome".